# combine 3 columns into 1 with header row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have got a data sheet where each item has a total of 3*3=9 columns attached to it. I want to split the columns in groups of 3 and then stack them vertically.

Input

[image]

Output

[image]

By using the formula below I managed to get 3 columns of a single row vertically stacked (note that it is in Dutch):

```
=LET(v;VERT.STAPELEN(HOR.STAPELEN($B4;$C4:$E4);HOR.STAPELEN($B4;$F4:$H4);HOR.STAPELEN($B4;$I4:$K4));ALS(v=0;"";v))
```

single row stacked

[image]

Trying to do this for multiple rows the formula becomes unnecessary long. This is for 2 rows:

```
=VERT.STAPELEN(LET(v;VERT.STAPELEN(HOR.STAPELEN($B4;$C4:$E4);
HOR.STAPELEN($B4;$F4:$H4);HOR.STAPELEN($B4;$I4:$K4));ALS(v=0;"";v));
LET(v;VERT.STAPELEN(HOR.STAPELEN($B5;$C5:$E5);HOR.STAPELEN($B5;$F5:$H5);HOR.STAPELEN($B5;$I5:$K5));ALS(v=0;"";v)))
```

Is there a better way to do this? Preferably without VBA since I do not have experience with that.

Comment: Just a question, in your Input, you have 2 times D2 and I6 where you'd expect H6 to be, is this intentional? I'm thinking about `ByRow` (same in Dutch) to use in your formula but since I'm not familiar with it, someone else will probably have answered you before I can manage to fiddle with it enough :p

Comment: @Notus_Panda My bad. second D2 should be E2 and I6 should be H6.

Answer (score 1):

How about this in `MS365`

[image]

---

```
=LET(
    x, HSTACK(
        TOCOL(
            IFNA(
                A2:A11,
                SEQUENCE(
                    ,
                    COLUMNS(
                        B2:J11
                    ) / 3
                )
            )
        ),
        WRAPROWS(
            TOCOL(B2:J11),
            3
        )
    ),
    IF(x = 0, "", x)
)
```

---

The `Dutch` Version will be

```
=LET(x;HSTACK(TOCOL(ALS.NB(A2:A11;SEQUENCE(;KOLOMMEN(B2:J11)/3)));
WRAPROWS(TOCOL(B2:J11);3));ALS(x=0;"";x))
```

---

You can actually resolve it using this formula only but it returns `0s` for the blanks, and `0s` can be hidden using custom format as well, but you can also wrap it within an `IF()` to show as blank.

```
=HSTACK(TOCOL(IFNA(A2:A11,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(B2:J11)/3))),WRAPROWS(TOCOL(B2:J11),3))
```

---

The first part of the formula returns an array of the `Stucklist`

[image]

---

• Formula is

```
=TOCOL(IFNA(A2:A11,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(B2:J11)/3)))
```

---

The second part of the formula where `WRAPROWS()` transforms this `TOCOL(B2:J11)` into a `2D array` having `3` values in each row.

[image]

---

```
=WRAPROWS(TOCOL(B2:J11),3)
```

---

Now, finally `HSTACK()` is used to combine both the arrays.

```
=LET(α,TOCOL(IFNA(A2:A11,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(B2:J11)/3))),
ß,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(B2:J11),3),
ψ,HSTACK(α,ß),
IF(ψ=0,"",ψ))
```

---

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I seem to be missing the TOCOL function

Comment: If you are `MS365` and current channel updates, you will get the `TOCOL()`, if not you might need to update or it can be Enterprise Version `LTSC` but I am not sure about it. I have to check the updates and confirm.

Comment: This is the version I currently have: Microsoft® Excel® voor Microsoft 365 MSO (Versie 2304 Build 16.0.16327.20302) 64 bits

Comment: Ah yes you do have the requisite version: per the documentation it shows **[Availability](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/tocol-function-22839d9b-0b55-4fc1-b4e6-2761f8f122ed)** for or higher **Windows: 2208 (Build 15601)**

Comment: @LarsNijkamp what does it show when you type while using the `TOCOL()`? and are you using `MAC` version of Excel

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

my input:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | G | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stucklist1 | A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | E1 | F1 | G1 | H1 | I1 |
| stucklist2 | A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | E2 | F2 | G2 | H2 | I2 |
| stucklist3 | A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | E3 | F3 | G3 | H3 | I3 |
| stucklist4 | A4 | B4 | C4 | D4 | E4 | F4 | G4 | H4 | I4 |
| stucklist5 | A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | G5 | H5 | I5 |
| stucklist6 | A6 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | G6 | H6 | I6 |
| stucklist7 | A7 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | G7 | H7 | I7 |
| stucklist8 | A8 | B8 | C8 | D8 | E8 | F8 | G8 | H8 | I8 |
| stucklist9 | A9 | B9 | C9 | D9 | E9 | F9 | G9 | H9 | I9 |
| stucklist10 | A10 | B10 | C10 | D10 | E10 | F10 | G10 | H10 | I10 |

Formula for the first column of the output (to be expanded down):

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10;ROUNDUP((ROW()-ROW($M$2)+1)/3;0);1)
```

`$A$1:$A$10` needs to be replaced by wherever the first column of your data is located, `$M$2` needs to be replaced by the **address where this formula will be placed**

Next, formula for the second column of the output (to be expanded right and down)

```
=INDEX($B$1:$J$10;ROUNDUP((ROW()-ROW($N$2)+1)/3;0);MOD((ROW()-ROW($N$2))*3+COLUMN()-COLUMN($N$2);9)+1)
```

`$B$1:$J$10` needs to be replaced by wherever your data is, but without the "stucklist" column. `$N$2` (appears 3 times) needs to be again replaced by the address of the cell where you will be putting this formula.

**resulting output:**

| M | N | O | P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stucklist1 | A1 | B1 | C1 |
| stucklist1 | D1 | E1 | F1 |
| stucklist1 | G1 | H1 | I1 |
| stucklist2 | A2 | B2 | C2 |
| stucklist2 | D2 | E2 | F2 |
| stucklist2 | G2 | H2 | I2 |
| stucklist3 | A3 | B3 | C3 |
| stucklist3 | D3 | E3 | F3 |
| stucklist3 | G3 | H3 | I3 |
| stucklist4 | A4 | B4 | C4 |
| stucklist4 | D4 | E4 | F4 |
| stucklist4 | G4 | H4 | I4 |
| stucklist5 | A5 | B5 | C5 |
| stucklist5 | D5 | E5 | F5 |
| stucklist5 | G5 | H5 | I5 |
| stucklist6 | A6 | B6 | C6 |
| stucklist6 | D6 | E6 | F6 |
| stucklist6 | G6 | H6 | I6 |
| stucklist7 | A7 | B7 | C7 |
| stucklist7 | D7 | E7 | F7 |
| stucklist7 | G7 | H7 | I7 |
| stucklist8 | A8 | B8 | C8 |
| stucklist8 | D8 | E8 | F8 |
| stucklist8 | G8 | H8 | I8 |
| stucklist9 | A9 | B9 | C9 |
| stucklist9 | D9 | E9 | F9 |
| stucklist9 | G9 | H9 | I9 |
| stucklist10 | A10 | B10 | C10 |
| stucklist10 | D10 | E10 | F10 |
| stucklist10 | G10 | H10 | I10 |

note: I am almost 100% certain that it's possible to create way simpler solution using new Excel 365 formulas, which I do not have access to.

Comment: Thank you! How would a formula look for 9 groups of 5 colums instead of 3 groups of 3?

Comment: @LarsNijkamp it shouldn't be difficult to modify it to whatever number of groups you need. You just need to replace some of the 3s in the formula by 5 or 9. Also the 9 in the second formula will have to be replaced by 45. I don't have time to do it right now but there isn't that many combinations, you can just try until you find the one that works.